# Append a file in the middle of another file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, merge, append

I need to append a file in a specific location of another file.
I got the line number so, my file is:

`file1.txt`:

```
I
am
Cookie
```

While the second one is

`file2.txt`:

```
a
black
dog
named
```

So, after the solution, `file1.txt` should be like

```
I
am
a
black
dog
named
Cookie
```

The solution should be compatible with the presence of characters like `"` and `/` in both files.

Any tool is ok as long as it's native (I mean, no new software installation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==3{system("cat file2.txt")} 1' file1.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
I
am
a
black
dog
named
Cookie
```

**Explanation:** Checking here if line number is 3 while reading Input_file named file1.txt, if yes then using system utility of awk which will help us to call shell's commands, then I am printing the file2.txt with use of cat command. Then mentioning 1 will be printing all the lines from file1.txt. Thus we could concatenate lines from file2.txt into file1.txt.

Comment: this worked! To understand your answer... the translation is:
when u arrive at line 3 cat file2.txt and then stop?
interesting use of system()..thnx!

Comment: @WyattGillette, you are welcome. Glad that it helped you, I just added explanation of same, kindly do let me know if you have any other queries on same.

Answer (score 9):

Another option apart from what RavinderSingh13 suggested using `sed`:
To add the text of `file2.txt` into `file1.txt` after a specific line:

```
sed -i '2 r file2.txt' file1.txt
```

Output:

```
I
am
a
black
dog
named
Cookie
```

Further to add the file after a matched pattern:

```
sed -i '/^YourPattern/ r file2.txt' file1.txt
```

Comment: also this one worked, i gave answer to the first due to chronological order :) 
btw, this means:
edit the stream at line 2 inserting file2.txt in file1.txt? Looks even simpler...

Comment: Means add lines of file2 after the 2nd line of file1. It doesn't invoke `cat` as in the other answer.

Comment: yup was easy with 'r' , how could I not think about it

Comment: Also, it is supposed that the accepted answer is the best answer, not the first anhway :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since allows one to add the contents of a file either after a specific line number or after a pattern

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
head -2 file1 && cat file2 && tail -1 file1
```

You can count the number of lines to decide `head` and `tail` parameters in file1 using

```
wc -l file1
```

Comment: creativity at work here
and it's working, good workaround
one point is: if the file is huge (ex. 5000+ lines) would be a problem to count tail parameter...easy to find head one (cat -n and grep)
one could do:
tac file2 > file3 && cat -n file3 | grep dog
to find the tail parameter, tough...funny way and working